# Error when calling object - Android

Tags: java, android, class, object

I'm calling the object here.

```
public class TestDetails extends ListActivity {

    protected TextView testNameText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected TextView testvalueText;
    protected List<TestAction> actions;
    protected TestItemAdapter adapter;
    protected int testId;
    protected int categoryId;

    @Override
    //adds options menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.list_search: onSearchRequested();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //end of add options menu
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_details);

     // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        SimpleSearch SSearch = new SimpleSearch();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent1.getAction())) {
          String query = intent1.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          SSearch.testSearch(query);
          }

        testId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.firstName, emp.lastName, emp.title, emp.officePhone, emp.cellPhone, emp.email, emp.managerId, mgr.firstName managerFirstName, mgr.lastName managerLastName FROM employee emp LEFT OUTER JOIN employee mgr ON emp.managerId = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+testId});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            testNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
            testNameText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));
            actions = new ArrayList<TestAction>();

            String officePhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("officePhone"));
            if (officePhone != null) {
                actions.add(new TestAction("Call office", officePhone, TestAction.ACTION_CALL));
            }

            String cellPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cellPhone"));
            if (cellPhone != null) {
                actions.add(new TestAction("Call mobile", cellPhone, TestAction.ACTION_CALL));
                actions.add(new TestAction("SMS", cellPhone, TestAction.ACTION_SMS));
            }

            String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
            if (email != null) {
                actions.add(new TestAction("Email", email, TestAction.ACTION_EMAIL));
            }

            categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerId"));
            if (categoryId>0) {
                actions.add(new TestAction("View manager", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerFirstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerLastName")), TestAction.ACTION_VIEW));
            }

            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE managerId = ?", 
                    new String[]{""+testId});
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int count = cursor.getInt(0);
            if (count>0) {
                actions.add(new TestAction("View direct reports", "(" + count + ")", TestAction.ACTION_REPORTS));
            }

            adapter = new TestItemAdapter();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    class TestItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TestAction> {
        TestItemAdapter() {
            super(TestDetails.this, R.layout.action_list_item, actions);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return false;
        }
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
           return false;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TestAction action = actions.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_item, parent, false);
            TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            label.setText(action.getLabel());
            TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            data.setText(action.getData());
            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

This is the class from which I'm calling the object.(part of the class)

```
public class SimpleSearch extends ListActivity {
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected String query;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          testSearch(query);
          }
        else TestListAll();
        }
```

But I'm getting a force close on running the application. Stack trace shows the error to be in `SSearch.testSearch(query);` statement. What am I missing here?

Stack trace:

```
app_vercode:1
device_model:umts_jordan
build_version:1.11.18
condition:1
processName:com.simple.search
pid:3529
uid:10063
tag:null
shortMsg:java.lang.NullPointerException
longMsg:java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simple.search/com.simple.search.TestDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
stackTrace:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simple.search/com.simple.search.TestDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.simple.search.SimpleSearch.testSearch(SimpleSearch.java:68)
at com.simple.search.TestDetails.onCreate(TestDetails.java:59)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
... 11 more
```

Comment: @kabuko Exception: `11-22 19:09:41.094: E/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simple.search/com.simple.search.TestDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You clearly haven't included the relevant code then. It might be in the testSearch method, maybe... just post the full stack trace, and while you're at it, maybe the code for the TestDetails activity as well.

Comment: Please add the additional details to the question, not in comments :)

Comment: Where are you setting the string extra that's keyed to SearchManager.QUERY?  What's the value of that string?  And what are the contents of TestSearch?  Also, your first code block indicates you're creating an Activity using the "new" keyword, which is odd.  If that's how you create the SimpleSearch object, no data will get passed into the onCreate method as a bundle.

Comment: @kabuko added stack trace and testdetails.

Comment: @alexander-lucas That is read from the searchdialog user input. You meant `SimpleSearch SSearch = new SimpleSearch();` right? What would you suggest for resolving this?

Comment: You are expecting a lot of keys in your intent - it maybe better to pass all the information in a custom Parcelable object that can verify the data is correct. Also - you should never expect a user to enter in valid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the line

```
String query = intent1.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
```

Is assigning a null value to query - are you sure the correct extra is there? I usually get extras in this manner:

```
public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
public static final String DATA_KEY = "DataKey";
public static final String MY_CUSTOM_ACTION = "MyCustomSearchAction";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    SimpleSearch SSearch = new SimpleSearch();
    if (intent1.getAction().equals(MY_CUSTOM_ACTION) 
          && intent1.hasExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)
          && intent.hasExtra(DATA_KEY)) {
        String query = intent1.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        DataObject data = intent1.getParcelableExtra(DATA_KEY);   
        if (query != null && data != null)
            SSearch.testSearch(query, data);
        else {
            //invalid query
           Log.d(TAG,"Activity started with invalid query data - closing");
           this.finish();
           return;
        }
    } else {
       //Invalid Intent
       Log.d(TAG,"Activity started with invalid intent - closing");
       this.finish();
       return;
    }
}
```

A data object can look like this:

```
public class DataObject implements Parcelable {

    public String someData;
    public String someMoreData;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(someData);
    dest.writeString(someMoreDate);
}

//Constructor for parceler
public DataObject(Parcel src) {
    someData = src.readString();
    someMoreData = src.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataObject> CREATOR = 
                new Parcelable.Creator<DataObject>() {

    public DataObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DataObject(in);
    }

    public DataObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DataObject[size];
    }
};
```

}

To start your activity just go:

```
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.someData = "test";
data.someMoreData = "test2";
Intent intent = new Intnent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setAction(MyActivity.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(MyActivity.DATA_KEY,data);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Query");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I added the code but Listdetails activity is not opening now.

Comment: TAG needs to be a String - sorry I usualy define a TAG variable in all my acivities.

Comment: I fixed that, but i think the problem is with the Activity using the "new" keyword like alexander said. Something to do with no data will get passed into the onCreate method as a bundle. Still trying to fix it.

Comment: If your activity is always expecting a large number of values in the bundle, you really should consider defining a a Parcelable object which has the data and sending just one object in your intent. I will give you an example in a moment

Comment: Added an example of using a Parcelable to send multiple values to an activity. The DataObject can also do data validation and logging to make it easier to find bugs. Also using static final Strings as Keys makes it far less likely for you to misspell a key name - a common cause of NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: I was working on that. Is there a way to declare an intent with custom action?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5451/discussion-between-binoy-babu-and-chris-noldus)

Comment: I just thought I might add that I don't recommend public instance variables (i.e. someData & someMoreData). I just used them here as an example - you should always use proper OO techniques.